# CSS3: how to skew x-angles of image in different directions using only 2D transform?

Tags: image, css, 2d, transform

Is it possible to skew the top and bottom edges of an image to go in different directions using only 2D transform? Here is what I am trying to do:

[image]

Comment: Using only 2D transforms? Nope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve is actually on 3 dimensions (the object will have left to right, up and down and the depth axis of close and far), so unfortunately 2d transform will not work in this case.